# Update Views With Spring MVC And Thymeleaf Without Redeploy The App

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Spring MVC 3.2, Thymeleaf, Thymeleaf dialect with Tomcat and every time that I change a view I don't want redeploy my app. As suggested from others I am setting:

```
<property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
```

in the template resolver, but it not working. 
Also a full reload (CTRL + F5) has not effect.

Here my full Thymeleaf configuration:

```
<!-- Thymeleaf template engine -->
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine"
      class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    <!-- These lines add the dialect to Thymeleaf -->
    <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
            <bean class="nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
</bean>
```

Is there something else that I can do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on many many things and mainly on "where and how" you update your view. If you are using a IDE (Netbeans or Eclipse) it main depend on the IDE itself and on the deployement process.

Current organization on disk :

> Source directories => [ on build ] => target or build directories => [ on deploy ] => tomcat directories

But IDE often tries to be developper's friendly and *it can happen that* target directories and tomcat directories are the same. But it also may depend of the IDE and its configuration.
Also when you save files under source webapp, the IDE *may* automatically copy them to target.

But this is not guaranteed by `<property name="cacheable" value="false"/>` of Thymeleaf config. All what it guarantees is that if a template is changed in tomcat directories, next request will use it.

So to be sure where the problem really comes, you will have to find where tomcat actually gets the templates and if *those* templates are modified.

(and I didn't even talked of browsers cache ...)

Comment: I use IntelliJ and on "Update" action I hot swap classes. Which it is not enough. 
What I need is to update classes and resources. Unfortunately I don't have this option and probably because of my maven build script.

Comment: Issue fixed. I didn't have the "update classes and resources" option because of the way I imported the project on IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat "Server Options", check "Serve modules without publishing" did the trick for me.